# Python - optimize matrix values using constraints, beginner

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I have an DataFrame in pandas with simple bond information. I need to create restrictions such that *at least* 30% of the bonds have to be long-term, or that *no more* than 60% of the bonds can be classified as high risk.  A simplified table is as follows:

```
Bond | Returns | Length | Riskiness

A    | 0.045   | Short  | Low    
B    | 0.030   | Short  | High    
C    | 0.050   | Long   | High
D    | 0.035   | Long   | Low
```

So essentially, how would I write code to get the maximum portfolio value while staying within the constraints? To be honest, I don't even know where to start.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you want to check whether constraints are insured or do you want to drop rows from your dataframe to fit your constraints?

Comment: Checking if the constraints are insured! Perhaps create a matrix and then solve it using those constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of `"Longs"` and `"Highs"` and divide by the total number of values using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
>>> sum(df["Length"] == "Long") / df["Length"].count() >= .3
True
>>> sum(df["Riskiness"] == "High") / df["Riskiness"].count() <= .6
True
```

Bear in mind, I'm using [Series.count()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html) to find the total number of values, which will not account `NaN` values. If you want to account `NaN` values as well, you can use `len(df["Length"])` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! 
Following up on it though, what statements would I write to solve for the final allocations (imagine **df** is exactly like the table)? The total allocation is $100,000.


Sorry if this is very basic, but I'm fairly new to python so almost all of the StackOverflow threads are too advanced to understand.

Comment: @MB_14 No worries, happy to help but I couldn't understand what you meant by final allocations (I'm a total noob when it comes to financing, so I may have missed it if it is related to Finance).

Comment: So basically, if the user has $100,000 and can get the stated returns with each bond (4.5%, 3%, 5%, 3.5% respectively), what would be the best way to allocate the money while staying within the constraints.  Ideally, you'd put all your money into the bond with the 5% return, but the constraints have to be followed.

Comment: @MB_14 ah got it now. It is a hard problem that probably best done with a heursitic. But you can brute force your algorithm to check the constraints while distributing amounts of money. Or you can use a heuristic that tries to optimize the gain while respecting constraints. Check [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-objective_knapsack_problem) it seems similar, and check meta-heurstic solutions like [Genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) they can be applied with a customized fitness function.

Comment: I'll try to implement something when I find time. But you may want to ask another question for that after some research.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help so far. I'll check out those links and see how I can implement it to solve the matrices. This was a great start and already helped push me in the right direction - thanks again!